# Is it possible to have multiple handlers for the same exception leveraging RESTEasy's ExceptionMapper?

Tags: jax-rs, resteasy, quarkus

When handling RESTEasy exceptions, it is typically very straightforward to perform custom exception handling (in this case, the intent is to handle marshalling issues when receiving an HTTP request):

```
@Provider
class MissingKotlinParameterExceptionHandler : ExceptionMapper<MissingKotlinParameterException> {
    override fun toResponse(exception: MissingKotlinParameterException?): Response {
        println("my MissingKotlinParameterException mapper")
        return Response.serverError().build()
    }
}
```

The particular challenge I'm experiencing, however, is when the same exception is thrown from different endpoints. For example, having `/service1/foo` and `/service2/bar`, due to architect specifications, return completely separate error payloads. Is it possible to separate the implementations based on some sort of configuration, or package structure?

Comment: You can use some kind of delegation pattern where a master ExceptionMapper delegates to different ExceptionMapper. There is also the option to make exceptions extend WebApplicationException where the Response can be provided. There are many things you can do, including injecting the ResourceInfo as suggested by geoand

Answer (score 1):

You can inject the resource info into the `ExceptionMapper` class using:

```
@Context ResourceInfo info; // this is the java version
```

Then in the `toResponse` use that field in order to determine the resource method that serviced the request.

Comment: While that allows for a `switch` statement (or an overloaded method), it's not going to scale well.

Comment: If you have suggestions for a better API, then we'd definitely like to hear them!